# Data loss Spark 2.1 -kafka broker 0.8.2.1 streaming

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

1  streaming and Kafka broker version 0.8.2.1, I have separate servers  for spark and kafka on AWS.

Using `val directKafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream` direct approach. `StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(300))`,  I am expecting to get 30 string from streaming  but actual receiving only 15-25 in range . Cross check  kafka consumer on same topic showing 30 string during 300 seconds. And  stream.foreachRDD { rdd => giving 15to 20 strings.

What is wrong behind getting uneventual data. I am using sparksession creating sc and ssc.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

add `auto.offset.reset` to `smallest` in kafka param

```
 val kafkaParams = Map[String, String](
         "auto.offset.reset" -> "smallest", ......)
```